# No valid certificate found in APK. The signature file must be called META-INF/CERT.RSA

Tags: android, apk, meta-inf, apksigner

I am trying to upload my apk to [Clover Marketplace](https://www.clover.com/appmarket). I signed my apk using apksigner with v1 signature. But when I upload my apk to Clover Marketplace I get this error.

[image]

**What am I missing?**

- My app does not have META-INF folder anywhere. How to fix this?

I used this command to sign my apk

```
java -jar apksigner.jar sign --ks mykey.jks --ks-key-alias mykey --v2-signing-enabled false  --v3-signing-enabled false --out myapp.apk  ~/Desktop/app-release.apk
```

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK META-INF/CERT.RSA is part of an app apk that is generated when you sign your app with keystore.

You can run this command to see

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs app/release/app-release.apk
```

[image]

### Why I was getting errors?

In my case somehow the files were saved as META-INF/KEY0.SF, META-INF/KEY0.RSA. I believe that Clover marketplace rejects the app if the files are not saved as CERT.RSA

### How did I fix it?

- I created a new keystore with keyalias "cert"
- resigned the apk.
- ran `jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs app/release/app-release.apk` to confirm

the files were renamed to META-INF/CERT.SF, META-INF/CERT.RSA

#### More discussion:

I don't know how the files got renamed after resigning the app. I tried again with another keyalias to see if it renames again. But it did not rename the files after they were renamed to CERT.RSA

Answer (score 0):

For people facing the same problem on windows

I removed `--v1-signer-name` from example command clover provided and it worked.

The final full command is

```
apksigner.bat sign --ks keystore.jks --v1-signing-enabled=true --v2-signing-enabled=false --v3-signing-enabled=false --in app-release-unsigned.apk
```