# Unable to add VersionCode to Test APK

Tags: android, gradle, junit, apk, clover-payment

I am trying to build an initial apk for a test suite that we intend to use for our Clover Payment Device development. Part of the requirements for this upload is a v1 signed apk (solved) with a versionCode (unsolved). For some reason, I can't compile a test apk that has a versionCode built into it.
I am building the apk with `gradlew assembleAndroidTest`
I am validating the apk with `aapt dump badging <path to apk>`

Here is the relevant snippet from my gradle file:

```
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        //noinspection ExpiredTargetSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 11 //project.bambooVersion.toInteger()
        versionName "1.0.1" //project.bambooVersionCode
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        buildConfigField("String", "PROTO_VERSION", '"' + versions.ethorProto + '"')
        buildConfigField("String", "CLOVER_SDK", '"' + clover_sdk + '"')
        buildConfigField("String", "VERSION_NAME", '"' + bambooVersionCode + '"')
    }

    signingConfigs {
        if (rootProject.file('key.properties').exists()) {
            debug {
                def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("key.properties")
                def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
                keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

                keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
                keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
                storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
                storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']

                enableV1Signing true
                enableV2Signing false
            }
        }
    }
```

I was very hopeful with this solution: [AndroidManifest in androidTest directory being ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244998/androidmanifest-in-androidtest-directory-being-ignored) but making a separate "debug" manifest hasn't resolved the issue.

Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Posting a "work-around" instead of an actual solution-- i.e. this works but it's ugly and it's not something I'd want to do on a routine basis.

1. Remove the signing code in gradle (you'll sign it at the end).
2. Build the test apk using `gradlew assembleAndroidTest`
3. Use [apktool](https://apktool.org/) to decode the apk with `apktool d <apkfile>`
4. In the decoded directory, edit the AndroidManifest.xml and put in your `android:versionCode` and `android:versionName` data
5. Rebuild your apk with `apktool b <decoded apk directory>`
6. Build your keystore but with "cert" as the alias (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73545449/no-valid-certificate-found-in-apk-the-signature-file-must-be-called-meta-inf-ce))
7. zipalign your apk first `zipalign -p -f -v 4 <source-apk> <dest-apk>`
8. sign your apk (make sure you're using a recent version of apksigner! this caught me up) with `apksigner.bat sign --ks <keystore_file> --v1-signing-enabled=true --v2-signing-enabled=false --v3-signing-enabled=false --v4-signing-enabled=false --in <dest-apk>`